# Can't touch second element in array

Tags: ios, calabash

I'm trying to touch a UITextField using Calabash. When I use `query("UITextField")[x]`, where x is the number in the array of text fields that are on screen, I can correctly query for just one text field. However, when I use `touch("UITextField")[x]` it will always touch the first text field. This happens when using the console and when using cucumber to run the tests.

Here's relevant info about my setup:

```
xcode-select --print-path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

xcodebuild -version
Xcode 7.2
Build version 7C68

calabash-ios version
0.16.4
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
touch("UITextField index:x")
```

where `x == your index`.

Also, please update to calabash 0.17.0 :)

#### Explanation

The Calabash environment is composed of a client and a server. The server runs on the device/simulator as part of the app and receives commands/queries from the client. In this case, the client is the ruby interface through which you are interacting with the app.

The client is responsible for sending enough info to the server to select objects on which to perform the gestures. Once the gestures / queries have been performed, results are sent back to the client as json / hashes, which is what you see in the console. The distinction is important: *the server performs the queries*, the client does not.

By the time you are seeing the results of a query / gesture in the irb console, it has already been performed: the json that is returned simply represents the state of the views, *not* the actual views themselves.

So when you are running

```
touch("UITextField")[index]
```

This is actually equivalent to

```
touch_results = touch("UITextField")
touch_results[index]
```

In the first line, `touch_results` is receiving the json representation of the elements affected by performing `touch` on the results of querying for `"UITextField"`, meaning that the `touch` event has already completed by the time you try to access the results with `touch_results[index]`.

Another way to think about it is this: Given `res = touch(query)`, the `query` is the part used to specify the actual views, and `res` is just json that represents the state of those views / results of a query or gesture.

#### In conclusion

When you need more specificity on a query, the specifiers need to go *inside* the query. E.g.,

```
touch("all UIScrollView UITextField marked:'some text' index:2")
```

(this will search for *all* *UIScrollViews* , find any *UITextFields* inside of them which contain text matching *'some text'*, and return the 3rd of such results).

For a full explanation of query language syntax, see [the docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/calabash/calabash-query-syntax/#Query_Syntax).

Comment: That did it! Your explanation makes a ton of sense also, thanks for including that!